# DBMS: concurrency control AKA the cup of cofee principle

Tags: database, concurrency

In French we call that problem of concurrency control the *cup of coffee principle*. It should be the same in English, shouldn't it?

Here's the principle. Let's imagine a hospital management system. A doctor uses application to display a Patient and modify it. Before clicking on "*Update*", he leaves for a coffee. Another doctor displays the same patient on his client application and clicks on "*Update*". When the first doctor came back, he clicks on "*Update*". Here's the problem: which update has to be accepted? Indeed, it is a rhetorical question: it is the developer/architect to answer it.

One solution I'm thinking about is to add a column "*locked*" in my tables. I set the boolean at **true** when I get the Patient for an update and set it to **false** when I've just updated it. Any "*Get for update*" will check if "*locked*" is set at **false** to allow writing.

Do you see any problem using this solution?

Answer (score 0):

> In French we call that problem of concurrency control the cup of
>   coffee principle. It should be the same in English, shouldn't it?

I've never heard it called that in English, but I understand what you mean. Database developers who speak English as a first language might not understand what you mean *before* you explain it, but they should *after* you explain it.

All modern databases implement transactions; proper use of transactions will guarantee the database behavior you want.

The "locked" column isn't necessary. If you maintain its state within a transaction, changes to its state won't be visible to other transactions. If you maintain its state outside a transaction, you risk its value being inconsistent with the real (dbms issued and maintained) locks.

Comment: I agree to delegate as much as possible the concurrency control to the database. But maintain a transaction during one hour because the doctor left for a coffee is not acceptable. This is why I was looking for a "*light weight*" locking system. So the "*locked*" patient can be read from everywhere but only written by one person. If the doctor left for one hour, the patient won't be editable but consider it as a requirement.

Comment: "But maintain a transaction during one hour because the doctor left for a coffee is not acceptable." I agree. But "locking" a row overnight while a doctor goes to sleep is equally unacceptable. A good user-interface programmer will begin transactions at the latest possible moment, and commit them at the earliest possible moment. The real problem isn't that modern dbms locking is too coarse and heavyweight; the real problem is that your user-interface programmer is treating your app like a single-user app, and he's beginning the transaction at the wrong time.